# ListBox in UserForm stops updating after 4 changes

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do a cell history where a userform with a listbox will popup when the cell is double clicked. But after 4 changes in the cell it doesn't show the changes see example :

Test10 doesn't show in the listbox

[image: Test10 doesn't show in the listbox].

The code for the sheet where I track is this one

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    celaddress = Target.Address
    colonne = Target.Column
    
UserForm1.Show

Target.Offset(1, 0).Select

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
        r = Target.Address & ")" & Target.Value
        c = Target.Column
        
With Worksheets("Update")

    dl = .Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row

If .Cells(dl, c) <> r Then .Cells(dl + 1, c) = r

    End With
End Sub
```

The code for my userform is this one:

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

UserForm1.Caption = "Historique des valeurs"

With Worksheets("Update")
    For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, colonne).End(xlUp).Row
        r = .Cells(i, colonne)
        s = InStr(r, ")")
    If s <> 0 Then If Left(r, s - 1) = celaddress Then ListBox1.AddItem Mid(r, s + 1)
        Next i
        
    End With

End Sub
```

And the code I have a module :

```vb
Public celaddress As String, colonne As Integer
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I tested the code successfully without issues. Pls verify the change is recorded on the `Source` worksheet.

Comment: So thinking about it logically, if some items are being added to the ListBox but others are not, it would appear that the 'If' statement is evaluating to False when you think it should evaluate to True ... so the first thing I would try is to add a line, immediately before the 'If', to print out the relevant values i.e. `Debug.Print i, r, s, Left(r, s - 1), celaddress` ... then, for the rows (ie values of i) that are not being added, check what values you see and work out why the 'If' is returning False

Comment: Also ensure you are using [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement) in all of your Modules (including the UserForm) otherwise your variables may not be holding the types/values you think they are